# Declative event listeners registration no longer supported in Hibernate 4.x/JPA 2?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, hibernate-4.x

I've noticed that the current Hibernate 4.2.x user guides and docs do not mention any way of declaring listeners in the persistence.xml file. Back in JPA 1.0, we could use properties such as:

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-insert" value="org.foo.MyPreInsertListener"/>
```

It seems that on JPA 2/Hibernate 4 it's only possible to register event listeners programmatically using an *org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator*. Is this true? Has the declarative registering of listeners gotten deprecated?